# subdomain and rewrite url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm searching a solution for my problem , I have a certain structure MVC in my PHP projet, if i want to execute or display a page , i tape on URL :  `mydomainname.com/index.php?do=agent` or `mydomainname.com/index.php?do=property` ...  where 'agent' and 'property' are my controllers.

Now i want to add a subdomain for each person i have in database, exemple : johnydeep.mydomainname.com  , and this URL must point on my controller 'agent'  like if i did : `mydomainname.com/index.php?do=agent&name=johnydeep`

Could you tell me if i should need Rewrite my URL ( apache htaccess)  or if there's any other method that's helps

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by Rewriting URL using htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?do=agent&name=%1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding , how about " RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  " , what does it mean for the server  and what about the rule "  ^(.*)$ /$1?do=agent&name=%1 " , can you explain me that ?